# Remove last node from linked list c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stack, singly-linked-list

I add elements to my Stack and print them in DataGridView.  It's working fine. But I cannot remove last element. Can you help me with my method?

Here how I search for last node:

```
public void RemoveLast()
        {

            STACKnode current = head, last;
            while (current != null)
            {
                last = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            last = null;
        }
```

But `last = null` doesn't remove node. However, if I would try to  change value `last.item`, it will be changed.

Full code of my linked list:

```
public class STACKnode
    {
        public STACKnode next;
        public int item;
    }

    public class LinkedList
    {
        private STACKnode head;
        public int currentItem;

        public void AddLast(int item)
        {
            if (head == null)
            {
                head = new STACKnode();

                head.item = item;
                head.next = null;
            }
            else
            {
                STACKnode newSTACKnode = new STACKnode();
                newSTACKnode.item = item;
                STACKnode current = head;
                while (current.next != null)
                {
                    current = current.next;
                }

                current.next = newSTACKnode;
            }
        }
        public void RemoveLast()
        {

            STACKnode current = head, last;
            while (current != null)
            {
                last = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            last = null;
        }
        public void printAllNodes(DataGridView dataGridView1)
        {
            STACKnode current = head;
            int i = 0;
            dataGridView1.RowCount = 1;
            while (current != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add("" + current.item);
                current = current.next;
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }}
```

sorry my bad English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assigning null to last, you are just changing the value of this variable. What you should do is change the "next" property of the node before it, so the link between them will break and thus effectively removing the last item. This should work:

```
public void RemoveLast()
    {
        STACKnode current = head, last;

        if (head == null) return;
        if (head.next == null){
            head = null;
            return;
        }

        while (current.next != null)
        {
            last = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
        last.next = null;
    }
```

Edit: Added a case for an empty list and a one node list.